# Chrome browser - Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
I am trying to launch the browser using Chrome Driver but getting Error as show below

**Java Code**
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver path");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

**Error in eclipse console**

Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19 (1bf021f248676a0b2ab3ee0561d83a59e424c23e-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#288}) on port 41104
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce00', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-OS8FHJPQQA', ip: '192.168.29.1771', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at SampleEHR/TestEHR.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:11)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:41104/status] to be available after 20011 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at com.google.common@25.0-jre/com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote/org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: What is the version of `chromedriver` ?

Comment: ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19, Browser version - 91.0.4472.164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the Antivirus firewall, I have just turned off the firewall and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The latest `stable` chromedriver is  **(As of 19th-July-2021)**

```
ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101
```

looks like, it's outdated in your case.

Please get it latest from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Comment: I have updated the chrome driver but still getting the same error

Comment: What Java version are you using  ? you may need to reboot also, I know it's not ideal but no harming give it a reboot and see if that works

Comment: I am using java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14

Comment: Your Selenium version also looks good, I think it could be Java version issue, Did you reboot and checked ?

Comment: Can you upgrade Java version if possible ? I am actually using `java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)` and it works fine on my machine

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but I am still facing the same problem

Comment: I am facing same issue "Timed out waiting for driver server to start" in windows 10, JDK 16.0.2, Chrome browser v92, Chrome Driver 92.

Nothing happens when I try opening chromedriver.exe in command line. Its staying there forever.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue "Timed out waiting for driver server to start" in windows 10, JDK 16.0.2, Chrome browser v92, Chrome Driver 92.

Nothing happens when I try opening chromedriver.exe in command line. Its staying there forever.